# Override X-UA-Compatible setting in web.config for specific pages and frames

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, internet-explorer, iis-7

I have a .Net web application that includes a web.config setting to force Internet Explorer to turn off compatibility mode and use the most recent version of IE available:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

However, this application contains a legacy page that requires Compatibility mode.  In my testing, it will only display properly when `X-UA-Compatible` is set to `IE=5`.

**Is there a way to override the web.config setting for a single page?**

Among the many things I have tried that have not worked:

- Including `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5" />` on the page itself, as the first tag after `<head>`
- Adding `X-UA-Compatible:IE=5` to the response headers.  Unfortunately, it also sends the `X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge` header, and that one 'wins.'
- Changing the `<!DOCTYPE >`.  I tried all the various options.
- Adding a comment before the DOCTYPE
- Re-writing the page to be standards-compliant.  This is obviously the best solution, but the page in question is a complex mapping application, and the re-write is going to take several months.

**Update**
When I called this "a complex mapping application," I should have said "a rat's nest of frames and tables."  It turns out that the frames part was relevant to the solution.

Comment: Have you tried removing the the existing X-UA-Compatible header first, before adding the second from the headers collection?  Have you also tried removing the doctype completely?

Comment: I had already tried both of these suggestions, but your suggestion to clear the headers spurred me to try the same thing on all the frames, so thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally got this fixed  by putting this code in the Page_Load() of every page that is part of the frameset for this page (about a dozen pages in total).

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=5");
```

I had been assuming that the frameset pages would inherit the setting from the main page, but apparently not.  Just putting that on the main page did not work, I had to put it on every page/frame.

Comment: Can I put this in the master.page ?

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a location tag...

```
<location path="YourPage.aspx">
    <system.webServer>
       <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
             <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=5" />
          </customHeaders>
       </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Comment: I had tried this, but I couldn't figure out a syntax that would also allow me to set <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" /> as a default for the rest of the site.  How do I include both?